# why it goes to a page when signout and press browser back button in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logout

I'm creating a login in c#, mvc. it works fine. Sign out is also working properly.
But after user signed out, if user press back button it goes to the page where I redirect if login success. I tried with following by adding it to `global.asax.cs`. but it didn't work. And also I tried using javascript. At that time if user press back button it shows the page and disappears. What can I do for that?

This is how I tried with c#

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

}

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-10));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You cant clear users history, but you can add redirect for unauthorized users from the page you redirect users after success login.